# Why does inserting an ObjectId reference in mongo using scala show up wrong

Tags: mongodb, scala

*Ignore org is a different key than organization*

I have the following code...

```
def getOrg = new ObjectId(orgId)
```

I would expect it to look like this in compass...

[image]

But instead it looks like this...

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that I was doing this before serializing into JSON. I removed the getOrg function on the domain object and added the following to the insert...

```
  val doc: Document = Document(json);
  doc.put("organization", new ObjectId(orgId))
  observable = collection.insertOne(doc);
```

Now it inserts as expected